# Failed to get void ponter as function arguments while calling function from application to Dynamic Loaded Library in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pointers, dll

I have created one dynamic library in Linux OS. There is one function called test which has one argument as `void *buffer`.

I have used mmap call inside that function which maps memory successfully without any issue.

I have mapped that memory into one global char *buffer inside dynamic loaded library.

**void *buffer;**

```
int test(void *buffer_app)
{
   buffer = (char *)mmap(0, buffer_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,  
   fd, 0);

   buffer_app = (char *)buffer;
   return 0;
}
```

Than, I have created one command line test application which will open that dynamic library using dlopen function.

All, above things works fine as per requirement.

After that, I have kept one `void *buffer` as global inside command line test application and passed it as argument of test function to map memory from dll.

```
void *buffer;

int main()
{
    void *handle;
    int status = 0;
    handle = dlopen("libtest.so", RTLD_NOW  | RTLD_GLOBAL);

    dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

    giPtr = dlsym(handle, "GI_Funcs");

    status = giPtr->test(buffer);

}
```

So, I am getting address of buffer as 0x0 instead of address which points memory called by mmap in dynamic library.

Does anyone has idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your dll function as:

```
int test(void *buffer_app)
{
   buffer = (char *)mmap(0, buffer_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,  
   fd, 0);

   *(char **)buffer_app = buffer;  /* Optional: No need to cast */
/* ^                           */
   return 0;
}
```

And later call it as:

```
status = giPtr->test(&buffer);
/*                   ^      */
```

You are passing pointer by value and the local value of pointer (argument) is being changed. Send the address of pointer to reflect the change in caller function also.

Comment: Thanks again for providing solution..It works for me..... But I just want to understand this solution. what is significance of this code line? *(char **)buffer_app = buffer;

Comment: @RiteshPrajapati When you want to change `int` variable in some other function, you pass address of `int` instead. Here you want to change `buffer`, so you pass `&buffer`. Now this address resides in a `void *` as per your design. And a `void *` can not be dereferenced. So first we cast the `void *` to the type of `&buffer` which is `char **` and then dereference it and save the value which would be visible in the caller function. You can alternatively take another variable `char **buf_in_app_addr = buffer_app; *buf_in_app_addr = buffer;`